# Invalid Signature error !

Tags: ios, ios4, app-store-connect

I am trying to update my application , but after uploading the binary , Itunes connect sends me this email :

> Dear Developer,   Thank you for your
>   recent binary submission for "MY APP"
>   to the App Store. Unfortunately we
>   discovered an issue with your binary
>   that you will need to correct in order
>   for your application to proceed to the
>   review stage. The specific issue is
>   outlined below:   Invalid Signature -
>   Make sure you have signed your
>   application with a distribution
>   certificate, not an ad hoc certificate
>   or a development certificate. Verify
>   that the code signing settings in
>   Xcode are correct at the target level
>   (which override any values at the
>   project level). Additionally, make
>   sure the bundle you are uploading was
>   built using a Release target in Xcode,
>   not a Simulator target. If you are
>   certain your code signing settings are
>   correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode,
>   delete the "build" directory in the
>   Finder, and rebuild your release
>   target.   Once you have corrected the
>   issue, please return to the
>   application's version details page in
>   the iTunes Connect Manage Your
>   Applications module and click on the
>   Ready to Submit Binary button. This
>   will take you through the binary
>   submission flow and return your
>   application version status to Waiting
>   for Upload. You can then use
>   Application Loader to upload your new
>   binary. If any other issues are found
>   with your submission you will be
>   contacted.   Thanks, The iTunes
>   Connect Team

[image]

I am sure that my binary  signed application with a distribution certificate NOT AD HOC !!!

what is your suggestion to solve this problem ! I NEVER HAD THIS PROBLEM !!!!!

I download the app distribution CER again but nothing change ! I have 6 apps on app store and never faced with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this QA is incredibly old.  Apple have largely ameliorated this problem.  Enjoy.

---

99 times out of 100, here is the problem:

#### Select "TARGETS", not "PROJECT"

Click on the name of your project at the Top Left of the main XCode6 window.  (ie, just above where it probably says "Classes".)

[image]

Look at the large area which opens.  Carefully look at the WHITE COLUMN ONTHE LEFT.

Choose "TARGETS" ... rather than "PROJECT"

**Then**, correctly set your certificate to the 3rd party Mac Developer cert.

Comment: The real question is why the validator/uploader doesn't catch this!

Comment: What is this "certificate" of which you speak? What's the name of the setting? I see a "Code Signing Identity", but that's for a provisioning profile - not a certificate.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same message appear from Apple, and selecting "targets" not "projects" when setting code signing identity did NOT resolve my issue.

Turns out, as the last step of submitting the app to the store (via XCode4's Organizer panel - Archives tab), I was presented with a dialog sheet that showed the distribution certificate it was going to be submitted with, which was DEFAULTING TO A DIFFERENT DISTRIBUTION CERTIFICATE I had in my keychain - and NOT the valid certificate that I'd signed the app with!

Once I manually selected the correct distribution certificate in this last step of app submission, it went through fine. (I also opened up my Keychain Access app and deleted the offending distribution profile, that I didn't have any use for anymore).

Answer (score 1):

A main point I'd like to offer is that Archive Validation (or submission thru App Loader) is **supposed** to identify the signature problem *before* sending the application to iTunes Connect. This is a first indication that the problem is related to a developer tools error.

Having witnessed this problem with multiple developers strengthens that hunch. In my experience the **"Invalid Signature"** diagnosis is not caught during client side validation as a result of a bug in older versions of Xcode. Devs simply update their OS X to 10.7.x, plus Xcode 4.2.1 and with no change to the project or code the app is ingested into iTunes Connect without issue.

Keep it in mind for others experiencing this problem...it's especially common on Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.0.2, 3.2.6 or less.

Apple's new publication touches on this point, see [iTunes Connect Store - Binary Rejection emails - Invalid Signature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2294/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011374-CH1-TNTAG4).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, checked everything but couldn't find any issues.

Problem ended up being because my project was stored on a FAT32 USB stick! Copied it to my Mac and everything worked perfectly after that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you provide more info? How does that affect the submission? Do you mean you were uploading to application loader directly from the USB disk?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and spent many evenings solving it!

For my app the problem was a **question mark in the executable name**. In the apple developer docs is noted you can't use special character in executable name but not which ones are allowed. 
I changed the executable name in build settings and the upload works!

Answer (score 0):

I have been battling this issue for almost a week! For me, it turned out that the Error email from Apple was completely wrong and misleading. (I knew that all of my certificates and code signing settings were in fact correct.) It turned out, that my app was getting rejected because there was an exclamation point (!) in the name. Apparently, only alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-9) and dashes are allowed for the product name. (Characters like ?#$% are not allowed.)

***The Fix:***

1.) Click on the blue project icon on the left panel in Xcode.

[image: Step 1]

2.) Click on the build settings tab.

3.) Select the current target from the menu. (It's right next to the blue project icon.

[image: Steps 2-5]

4.) Scroll down until you see the "Packaging" Category.

5.) Find where it says "Product Name" and change it to a name that does not contain any special characters.

[image: Step 6]

I hope this helps! Sorry I had to red-out my company info!