# Issue about 'Invalid Signature' on iTunes Connect

Tags: ipad, binary, signature

Recently I created an application for iPad. I created the binary(something.zip) and uploaded that via Application Loader, but the result of uploading was 'Invalid Binary' always.
and I received this email from apple when my app was denied from them due to the issue 'Invalid Binary' :

**"Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target."**

I searched the web from around the world to solve this annoying problem, but I cannot see the good answer. Here's the data of my application's info.plist :

**Localization native development region : English
Bundle Display name : $(PRODUCT_NAME)
Executable fike : $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
CFBunldleIconFiles :Icon-Small.png(29x29), Icon.png(57x57), Icon-Small-50.png(50x50)
(all files were created as 72ppi, RGB, flattened, No transparency)
InfoDictionary version : 6.0
Bundle name : $(PRODUCT_NAME)
Bundle OS Type Code : APPL
Bundle creator OS Type Code : ????
Bundle Version : 1.0
LSRequiresiPhoneOS : Enabled
UIPrerenderedIcon : Enabled
UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend : Disabled
UIStatusBarHidden : Disabled****

and I created this application with these tools - 
cocos2d Ver0.99.4-rc3 / 
xcode Ver3.2.5 64-bit / 
iOS SDK 4.2

I tried to solve this problem for 3 days, but I couldn't.

Is there anybody who can solve my application's problem, It's an emergency issue of our company.

Thanks everyone

Comment: As a registered Apple IOS Developer, have you obtained your digital certificates and read the documentation?

Comment: @Laza click here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056699/invalid-signature-error

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are a LOT of causes for receiving this cryptic and mostly unhelpful email. Even after verifying the use of distribution certificates, cleaning & rebuilding my project, and checking with codesign from the command line (and following instructions from the email), no errors showed up—-but I'd get the "invalid signature" email right after uploading. All the solutions seem anecdotal and obviously depend on what secret error is causing the problem. I've spent the last week pulling my hair out, trying to figure it out for my app—-and finally got it successfully submitted today—so let me share my story and see if it's relevant to your situation.

In my case, I seemed to have a complex cause of having my Entitlement.plist set with an incorrect variable along with the holdover of an old provisioning profile (from a previous Xcode version?) buried deep in the project.pbxproj component of my Xcode project file.

The "aps-environment" variable in my Entitlements.plist was set to "distribution" instead of "production" (I swear I read somewhere in the developer docs that it was supposed to be "distribution"!) But fixing that alone wasn't enough to get my app through. (I must have submitted 100 different combinations of app configurations trying different variables!) Starting with [the helpful suggestions from this post on another forum](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9167082#9167082), I dug through the distribution profile and found duplicate entries for some variables. The duplicates had empty quotation marks (i.e. nothing set for the variable) or strange variables or old provisioning profiles which seemed to be causing problems (somehow). Cleaning this up and removing the duplicate lines with bad variables worked in my case. YMMV. But carefully examining the project files ("show contents" on the Xcode project file in finder) seems like a good idea for diagnosing. Good luck!

Comment: @Luben click here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056699/invalid-signature-error

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying issue, I spend a lot of hours in trying to find a solution but at the end this was corrected for me by removing the Entitlements.plist (as I understood it is only needed when deploying for ad hoc), removing any duplicate field in the Info.plist, setting the target to "Distribution" with the correct configuration of the certificates and using the method of "Archive" then "Validate" and at last "Submmit" in XCode