# Invalid signature when uploading iphone app

Tags: iphone, store, loader, submission

Im getting the following error:

Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or not it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.

I uploaded this same app a month ago and it was rejected by the appstore.
I fixed my errors and now I'm trying to re-upload it but its failing. 
I'm using the same certificate that worked the first time.
I'm doing it the same way that worked the first time..

Can any one help?

Comment: click here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056699/invalid-signature-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved the problem..I was not building the app on the phone but on the simulator.
I built it on the device and it submitted fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the certificate's expiry date..

Comment: thanks but no its not that. 
The certificate in my key chain expire 30 Mar 2012.
The provisioning certificate in my organizer expires 29 Mar 2012.
Any other suggestions?